# my function works in java but when i put it in my javafx controller the function only gives a false boolean output

Tags: java, javafx

Function for my button, when pressed it changes my imageview.

```
    public void checkWebsite(ActionEvent event) {
    String url = "https://" + urlInput;

    if (testConnectionTo(url) == true) {
        System.out.println("boolean true");
        img.setImage(new Image("/image/safe.png"));
    } else if (testConnectionTo(url) == false) {
        System.out.println("boolean false");
        img.setImage(new Image("/image/unsafe.png"));
    }
}
```

Function for checking the website certificate.

```
    public static boolean testConnectionTo(String aURL) {
    try {
        URL destinationURL = new URL(aURL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
        for (Certificate cert : certs) {
            if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
                ((X509Certificate) cert).checkValidity();
            }
        }
        return true;

    } catch (CertificateExpiredException e) {
        return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Inside my java file it works perfectly fine (valid certificate will return true output, invalid certificate will return false output)

however when i put my function to check the certificate, it only returns a false output and i am not sure why.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note the information about mcve and post title.

Comment: So what exception is it that you're throwing and catching?  Get rid of the exception handling from `testConnectionTo` and look at the stack trace.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem im sorry i do not understand what you mean, my coding is not very good

Comment: the CertificateExpiredException checks whether the certificate is within expiry date.

Comment: `if (testConnectionTo(url) == true) { ... } else if (testConnectionTo(url) == false) { ... }` this can and should be rewritten as `if (testConnectionTo(url)) { ... } else { ... }`. Also you can use multi catch to handle different types of exceptions the same way: `catch (ExceptionType1 | ExceptionType2 ex) { ... }` however since `CertificateExpiredException` is a subtype of `Exeception` in this case you should simply use `catch (Exception ex) { ... }` instead of adding a catch clause for a exception type that would be caught by this clause as well...

Comment: BTW: What DawoodibnKareem tries to tell you is: use `e.printStackTrace()` before returning in the catch clauses and [edit] the question to include the stacktrace printed to the console.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I went away for a while.  What fabian says is right.  When an exception gets thrown, it has information in it telling you what's wrong.  What your method is doing is throwing away all of that information, then returning false.  I don't know what kind of exception you're getting - it probably isn't a CertificateExpiredException.  But if you don't print its stack trace, you'll never know.

Comment: Or in short - don't use `try` and `catch` unless you know what they do.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Your advise helped alot! Much appreciated :)